# Running a Web Server Over My Network

Tags: router, wireless-router, home-networking

I am hoping to run a small web server on my computer to let other people in my house access it (common tips, etc.) and that would be easy enough to do and host at my IP address

```
http://192.168.1.100
```

However, I want it to be simple for my family with lesser tech knowledge. I want them to be able to go to a URL like

```
http://help
```

and to be able to get it from there.

I was thinking that I could edit hosts files and such to point the domain "home" to my IP address, but 1) that requires a lot of setup, and 2) that won't automatically work on all devices. Some, like iOS devices, will automatically be excluded since hosts files can't be edited.

So I was thinking that through some router setting, or DNS, I could achieve this. My router is a Linksys E1550. I think Amahi Home Server can (or did at some point) do something like this...

But my question is how I can pull this off?

Comment: You can set up a forwarding DNS server with custom records and point your DHCP server to it so all clients will automatically use it. I don't know Amahi; but I remember that it's based on Ubuntu. Is this right?

Comment: No - I want to set this up on Windows in some way. Just to change "http://something" to "192.168.1.XXX"

Comment: Okay, you can use a DNS server or edit all `hosts` files manually. Where do you want to host the DNS server? On Windows?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/DNSMasq_as_DHCP_server  If your linksys firmware does not support any dns settings you may want to consider using dd-wrt firmware on the linksys.  It appears it allows that funconality and your router is supported.

You may also need to run your own caching dns server on the webserver so that all local network systems can resolve and go to that dns server for all internet resolutions as well.  Added bonus is that if your isp dns server goes down and you have a proper config you can keep surfing while every one else is down.

Those are the 2 choices I can see. you may be able to get ICS or something already on the pc to do basic dns as well but may be more prone to breakage.  I used a really simple and basic dns server many years agao in windows but cant rmember off hand what it was called.